# Is it possible to test your react app entry point with jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I have a react app which has the following entry point:

```
// Import dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import Root from './containers/Root';

const store = configureStore({});
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

render(
  <Root store={store} history={history} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

A pretty common configuration. I'm wondering how you would test something like this since it doesn't export anything, and jest relies on importing what you want to test.

Comment: Or is testing code like this unnecessary anyway?

Comment: Testing an entry point is an integration test. Your Jest tests would start at `<Root>`. Testing that it gets rendered into the application would either be a simple sanity check ("Did stuff show up?") or an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably don't need to test this, but you absolutely can.

If you **really** want to do this you would need to restructure your code a bit so that there is a function to test:

```js
// Import dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import Root from './containers/Root';

export const app = () => {
   const store = configureStore({});
   const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

   render(
     <Root store={store} history={history} />,
     document.getElementById('react')
   );
};
```

Then you can use something like react testing library to ensure that you're mounting your `Root` component in the proper element:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { app } from './app';

test('app should render the Root component into the expected element', () => {
   // render the document with the element we plan on using for our react app
   render(<div id="react" />);

   // invoke the function that will render our component into that element
   app();

   // assert that the component exists in the document
   // you can mock `Root` to be some element you expect to see in the test
   // for the sake of this example, since I know nothing about `Root`
   // let's assume it has some identifying text
   expect(screen.getByText('rooty tooty toot toot')).toBeInTheDocument(); 
});
```

So that would allow us to text the work being done in the entry point, but now it's a function that needs to be invoked!  For your app to work, your entry point needs to import the `app` function and invoke it:

```js
import { app } from './app';

app();
```